# Should List<T>.Remove be preceded with List<T>.Exists?

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics

Having `List<string> paths = new List<string>();` I want to  remove item that I'm not sure is there. Should I check if it exists or just run the Remove method straight ahead?

Is `if (paths.Exists(stringVar))` needed or considered a good practice before `paths.Remove(stringVar)`?

Running Remove without Exists would simply return false in case there is no such item in list.

Comment: it does not throw an exception though it will always good practice to check for the existence before removing the item.it will not hurt :)

Comment: @Devjosh: It is unnecessary and **will** hurt in performance critical situations with big lists, because with the additional check, the list is traversed twice instead of once.

Comment: @daniel thanks i was not knowing the default behavior of remove method

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No it doesn't throw an exception, and there is no need for extra checking . see [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e.aspx):

> true if item is successfully removed;
>   otherwise, false. This method also
>   returns false if item was not found in
>   the List.

Comment: Theoretically this is true. However, I did encounter a situation where I had multiple threads accessing the Remove and occasionally encountered an IndexOutOfRange exception emitting from somewhere in the implementation. I ended up making it an ImmutableList to address the issue.

Comment: @DiamondBack, This is correct theoretically and practically when you use it in a single thread. Normal lists do not claim to be thread-safe, for that you may use the corresponding data structures designed for. Even if you first were going to check the existence of the element, you could have run into the same exception when removing an element. To perform the operation fast, standard data structures do not use the lock/unlock procedure as it adds overhead, but concurrent lists/queue/... do have supports for multithreading.

Answer (score 13):

No, don't check. Because `Remove` already does the check. Your extra check is simply superfluous and brings no benefit.

Comment: Not only doesn't it add benefits, but it requires another scan of the list (which is O(N))

Comment: Right. I already pointed that out in my comment to Devjosh's comment on the question.